# $ \left( f_k:x \mapsto \chi_k(x) \left(1-\frac{x}{k}\right)^k e^{x/2} \right)_k$ is increasing; [monotone convergence theorem]

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Consider the sequence of functions

$$k\mapsto  \left( f_k:x \mapsto \chi_k(x) \left(1-\frac{x}{k}\right)^k e^{x/2} \right)$$

where $\chi_k$ is the characteristic function of the interval $[0,k]$ and each $f_k$ is defined over $[0,+\infty).$

> Is this sequence increasing?

**My reasoning**

Let $k<k+1.$ For $x>k+1,$ we have $f_k(x)=f_{k+1}(x)=0;$ for $0\leq x\leq k+1,$ we have 
$$\left(1-\frac{x}{k+1}\right)^{k+1}\geq \left(1-\frac{x}{k}\right)^k$$ and so $f_{k}(x)\leq f_{k+1}(x).$

**Why I am asking the question**

I'm reading some notes where the limit $\lim_{k\to +\infty} \int_{[0,k]}  \left(1-\frac{x}{k}\right)^k e^{x/2} \ dx$ is evaluated using dominated convergence theorem, while I would have used monotone convergence.

> Is there some reason why we can't use monotone convergence theorem as I would have in this case, that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually for $x=2.5$ and $k=2$ we have$$\left(1-\frac{x}{k+1}\right)^{k+1} \approx 0.00462963 < 0.0625 \approx \left(1-\frac{x}{k}\right)^{k}$$so your reasoning is incorrect there. I think you actually need dominated convergence.

Comment: ah, because for any $x$ such that $k< x \leq k+1,$ $x/k$ is $>1$ while $x/k+1\leq 1$ and then my reasoning does not work.

Comment: thanks---------